# How did you compatible android app UI with multiple screen size?

Tags: android, user-interface

One of challenges in developing android applications is compatible app's UI with different screen sizes, Now i'm using smallest width in dimens and specifying sizes in `DP`and `SP`for multiple devices for make my app UI compatible with diffrent screen sizes which solution is better than using smallest width to compatible app's UI or what is you solution for that?

Comment: Please check my this answer, you will get idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49630287/android-layout-size-issue-when-changing-device-settings/49631729#49631729

Answer (score 0):

I think, there are many ways to achieve this what i have learned in two years I can summarize here,

- Use in-bulit width height - i.e. Match_parent and Wrap_content
- For fixed width height - One can you Linear layout and divide it in screen %
- If there are shape which need to be shown like circle or anything create layout, or instead of using images for gradient create them
- Try to minimize use of images and incase use
  them, put all [vectored images](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio) in respective folders.
- For some layouts - Like showing circles overlapping as per width , try to do
  that programmatically where need to get height and width of screen and
  then need to lill bit of math to make it dynamic
- Use dp for widgets and views height width parameter Use sp for fonts
- Put all in style,dimen respective pages and use from there
- There are many standard things which need to keep in mind while creating UI like heard size is 44dp etc. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/

So its just matter of experience just avoid fix values and for even for simplest things google how other ppl have done it try to get their views and you're good  to go.